# Launching Two Node Child Processes From Single Gulp File Results In Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'd like to manage two apps with one gulpfile.  I can launch them both with the following code.  However, when I modify one of the files, and gulp.watch restarts the server, I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`.  Something must be wrong in my gulp `server` task, but what is it?

```
// Dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp'),
spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
node;

// Server Task
gulp.task('server', function() {
  if (api) node.kill();
  if (dashboard) node.kill();

  var api = spawn('node', ['./api/server.js'], {
    stdio: 'inherit'
  });
  var dashboard = spawn('node', ['./dashboard/server.js'], {
    stdio: 'inherit'
  });

  api.on('close', function(code) {
    if (code === 8) console.log('API – Error detected, waiting for changes...');
  });
  dashboard.on('close', function(code) {
    if (code === 8) console.log('Dashboard – Error detected, waiting for changes...');
  });
});

// Watch Statement
gulp.task('default', ['server'], function() {

    // Watch files for changes
    gulp.watch(alljsLocations, ['server'], function() {});

});
```